# How to loop or shorten this script in R

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot about 50 of these graphs that I only need to change the x, y and data of. Is there a way to shorten this to make it look less messy? without downloading any external libraries.

RatingsA, RatingsB and Looks are vectors with around 100k values e.g. ("Null", 439..., etc)

```
#Plotting graphs based based on Looks Vs Ratings
png('1.png')
par(mfrow=c(4,2))
plot(RatingA ~ Age, main="Looks Vs RatingA at List1", xlab="Looks",     ylab="RatingA", xlim=c(20,80), data=List1)
plot(RatingA ~ Age, main="Looks Vs RatingA at List2", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingA", xlim=c(20,80), data=List2)
plot(RatingA ~ Age, main="Looks Vs RatingA at List3", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingA", xlim=c(20,80), data=List3)
plot(RatingA ~ Age, main="Looks Vs RatingA at List4", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingA", xlim=c(20,80), data=List4)
plot(RatingA ~ Age, main="Looks Vs RatingA total", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingA", xlim=c(20,80), data=mainlist)
dev.off()

png('2.png')
par(mfrow=c(4,2))
plot(RatingB ~ Looks, main="Looks Vs RatingB at EVR1", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingB", xlim=c(20,80), data=List1)
plot(RatingB ~ Looks, main="Looks Vs RatingB at EVR2", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingB", xlim=c(20,80), data=List2)
plot(RatingB ~ Looks, main="Looks Vs RatingB at EVR3", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingB", xlim=c(20,80), data=List3)
plot(RatingB ~ Looks, main="Looks Vs RatingB at EVR4", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingB", xlim=c(20,80), data=List4)
plot(RatingB ~ Looks, main="Looks Vs RatingB total", xlab="Looks", ylab="RatingB", xlim=c(20,80), data=mainlist)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Consider what the following snippet of code does. `for(i in c("A","B")) print(paste0("Var", i))`

Answer (score 1):

Put them into a **function**. The parameters are variables which you wanna change, i.e `x`, `y`, `data`.

```
plot_graph <- function(x, y, data)
{
        your code here, you need to change the original code a little bit, 
    by putting x, y, data instead of specific values.
}
```

Whenever you wanna plot a graph, just call the function:

```
plot_graph(x_value, y_value, your_data)
```

Now, it's much more clear.

Then, you can use a `for` loop, or `apply` function (or some kinda function can *map*, I mean it can split the data into multi parts, then apply the function to each part.)

Example with for loop:

```
#vector x_vector store 50 values for x
x_vector = c(x1_value, x2_value,   ,x50_value)

#do the same with y_vector, data
y_vector = c(y1_value, y2_value,   ,y50_value)
data= c(data1, data2,   ,data50)

#plot 50 graghs
for (i in 1:50)
    plot_graph(x_vector[i], y_vector[i], data[i])
```

You can also use `apply` function (functional programming). It's better than for loop, but a little bit more complex.

Comment: this would be better placed in the comment section

Comment: @abhiieor: yes, using it with apply function, or just a for loop.

Comment: With the bit where you mention of putting "your code here" could you elaborate a bit more as that bit is what i'm qutie confused with right now. The rest though works :D.

Comment: @OwnThisField: ok, but at first, I need to know what is the "x", "y", "data" in your code, when you say " I only need to change the x, y and data of"

Comment: The y is RatingsA or RatingsB, the x is Looks. Looks is a vector with values ranging from 1 - 100. RatingsA and RatingsB are vectors that ranges from null - over 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

Generalize your plotting code in a function. I think there is a typo in your question, the title of the first set of plots should probably say "Age vs RatingA". If you really want plot titles with numbers, add another argument to the function, and use it in `png`. Feed it into `map` later on as the third argument.

```
func_plot = function(x, y) {
  png(paste0(x, ".png"))
  par(mfrow=c(4,2))
  f = as.formula(y~x)
  plot(f, main=paste0(x, " Vs ", y, " at EVR1"), xlab=x, ylab=y, xlim=c(20,80), data=List1)
  plot(f, main=paste0(x, " Vs ", y, " at EVR2"), xlab=x, ylab=y, xlim=c(20,80), data=List2)
  plot(f, main=paste0(x, " Vs ", y, " at EVR3"), xlab=x, ylab=y, xlim=c(20,80), data=List3)
  plot(f, main=paste0(x, " Vs ", y, " at EVR4"), xlab=x, ylab=y, xlim=c(20,80), data=List4)
  plot(f, main=paste0(x, " Vs ", y, " Total"), xlab=x, ylab=y, xlim=c(20,80), data=mainlist)
  dev.off()
}
```

Run function for your list of things to iterate over.

```
Map(func_plot, c("RatingA", "RatingB", etc), c("Age", "Looks", etc))
```

Comment: Not sure whats wrong here but it isn't giving me the correct graph. Instead one full of NA's

Comment: What does 'graph full of NA's` mean?

Comment: It plots me a graph full of Null values instead.

Comment: I think its something with the the xlab and ylab as the vector x and y have more than one value in their objects.

Comment: I think i managed to fix somethings on my end but the "data=" never seems to read the right data.

Comment: @OwnThisField xlab and ylab are just text strings. They have no impact. `List1-4` are named lists, but they need to be data.frames. Data.frames don't allow for columns with different lengths (unless you NA or 0 pad) so x and y should never be of different length.